# call getter of property after getting value from variable

Tags: java

I am trying to call getter method on object but which getter to call depends on the value in a variable.

```
public void met1(String var) {
    MyClass m = new MyClass();

    if(var.equals("A"))
        m.getA();
    if(var.equals("B"))
        m.getB();
    if(var.equals("C"))
        m.getC();
}
```

This is one way. Another could be using `switch` but I don't want to hardcode values as they may change. Is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: Please explain a little bit better your problem, and add some else in your example.

Comment: @ÓscarAndreu else will throw exception. That is not part of my question. I just need to check if there is any better way to achieve this instead of checking each and every value.

Answer (score 1):

String is a class not a primitive type, you can't compare instances of String class like var using `==` this will not work!!!

You need to use method `equals` like: `if(var.equals("A")) then ...` .
Apart form that this way is fine.

Another way would be using reflection without if-statement:

```
    Class<?> c = Class.forName("MyClass"); 
    Object my_object = c.newInstance(); 
    Method setNameMethod = my_object.getClass().getMethod("get"+var,String.class);
    setNameMethod.invoke(my_object, var);
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question. But I don't feel comfortable hardcoding values as "A", "B", "C" etc.

Comment: What do you mean by **don't feel comfortable hardcoding** ? If you are comparing Strings then you must store it somewhere; may be on some constant variables/ enums.